файл помощи .chm не отображает в оглавлении буквы казахского алфавита
Нужно сделать файл справки .chm. Столкнулся с проблемой: казахские символы не отображаются в содержании файла справки. Скрины прикладываю. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить?
Пробовал собирать в разных программах, результат один.

Нужно смотреть как создаете chm, там уже смотреть как кодировку настроить

Программа использует другую кодировку (вероятно, windows-1251). В файле конфигурации должен быть параметр для настройки кодировки либо настройка кодировки может быть где-то в GUI.
